# Getting the path of folder when a file is pasted into it

Tags: java

How to generate an event when the paste option(while copying a file) is selected in some folder, in which that event should get the path of that folder where the paste option is being selected.

Answer (score 2):

This code watch a directory for file added, removed or modified:

```
Path testDirectory = Files.createTempDirectory( getClass().getName());
WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
testDirectory.register( watcher,
    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, 
    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY, 
    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE );
for(;;) {
   WatchKey key = watcher.take();
   log( "key = watcher.take()" );
   if( key.isValid()) {
      log( "key.isValid()" );
      List< WatchEvent< ? >> lst = key.pollEvents();
      for( WatchEvent<?> e : lst ) {
         log( "WatchEvent polled: " + e.kind() + ": " + e.context());
         if( e.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE ) {
            Path path = (Path)e.context();
            File file = path.toFile();
            addFile( new File( testDirectory.toFile(), file.getPath()));
         }
         else if( e.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE ) {
            Path path = (Path)e.context();
            File file = path.toFile();
            removeFile( new File( testDirectory.toFile(), file.getPath()));
         }
      }
      key.reset();
   }
}
```

The classes involved in this code are:

- [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)
- [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)
- [StandardWatchEventKinds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardWatchEventKinds.html)

[This part of the io tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) shows more and explain the motivations of this API.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java) is an Java tutorial of the desired.  `java.nio.file` package provides a file change notification API, called the Watch Service API. This API enables you to register a directory (or directories) with the watch service. When registering, you tell the service which types of events you are interested in: file creation, file deletion, or file modification

More on it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

Comment: I didn't want to have that watcher for not a single directory or some list of directories. I want a listner for the entire system, wherever the pasting work is being carried out.